# Angular2 DateTimePicker, configure systemjs.config.js file

Tags: datetime, angular, ng2-datepicker

I'm trying to use an Angular2 component for show a dateTimePicker, the ng2-datetime-picker (https://github.com/ng2-ui/ng2-datetime-picker) into my Angular2 app. 
Tutorial says

> add map and packages to your systemjs.config.js
>   map[‘ng2-datetime-picker'] = 'node_modules/ng2-datetime-picker/dist';
>   packages[‘ng2-datetime-picker'] = { main: 'ng2-datetime-picker.umd.js', >defaultExtension: 'js’ }

but i can't find any systemjs.config.js

Where i can find it?

Comment: from where you downloaded project ? i mean using angular-cli ?

Comment: i've add "ng2-datetime-picker": "0.13.0" string into package.json file and installed it